# Using the Anymote library for an Android mobile application to communicate with Android TV

Tags: android, mobile, bouncycastle, android-tv, anymote

**General use case:**

For my project I'm trying to implement several easy games like Pong or a simple quiz for Android TV. The TV respectively Android TV box displays the game and handles the logic (Separate module). Smartphones and tablets should act as simple controllers for these games (Separate module). For example: When playing Pong, the application on the phone just shows 2 arrows for moving the player's paddle up or down. For the connection and communication between the app on the TV and the app on the mobile device, the *Google Nearby Connections API* is used.

**The actual problem:**

The requirement is now that the user can start the Pong game from his phone. That means: He opens the simple controller app on his mobile device, chooses a pseudonym and then decides if he wants to start a new Pong game or if he wants to join an existing Pong game. So that when the user wants to start a pong game, he should be able to push a button on the screen and the application on the Android TV would get started (If not already running).

I did a lot of research on this and sadly had to find out that there are not much examples or source code available for this kind of feature. Luckily, I found then the source code for the official *Google TV Remote application* (I can not add the link as my reputation is too low yet).

I've been aware that it's an app for the older *Google TV* and not *Android TV*. But while taking a look at it, I found out that there is the  *AnymoteLibrary* which exactly offers the kind of functionality I want. I downloaded it from here: https://github.com/google/googletv-android-samples

**Where I am blocked at the moment:**

So, I took the *AnymoteLibrary* from the link above and imported it to my existing project in Android Studio as a separate module. After some import fixes and Gradle cleans, I thought it might work. I adapted the *build.gradle* file which looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
    //compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.6.1'
    compile files('libs/anymote.jar')
    compile files('libs/bcprov-jdk15-143.jar')
    compile files('libs/polo.jar')
    compile files('libs/protobuf-java-2.2.0-lite.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
```

}

and added and adapted the *BlackJackRemoteActivity.java* from the directory *googletv-android-samples/BlackJackTVRemote/src/com/example/google/tv/remote/blackjack/* from the above link to my use case on the mobile module. With that I just wanted to test if I can get control the Android TV from my app and so I tried to run it. At first the app starts and it seems to work (See the following log messages) but then I get an exception:

```
E/KeyStoreUtil: Key store missing identity for anymote-remote
V/KeyStoreUtil: Generating key pair ...
V/KeyStoreUtil: Generating certificate ...
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class      'org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider', referenced from  method com.google.polo.ssl.SslUtil.generateX509V1Certificate
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 9479      (Lorg/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider;) in   Lcom/google/polo/ssl/SslUtil;
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class   'org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider', referenced from  method com.google.polo.ssl.SslUtil.generateX509V3Certificate
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 9479   (Lorg/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider;) in   Lcom/google/polo/ssl/SslUtil;
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception   (group=0x416a0e18)
```

The final exception message:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                              Process: androidtvportablecontroller, PID: 23592
>                                                                                              java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
>                                                                                                  at com.google.polo.ssl.SslUtil.generateX509V3Certificate(SslUtil.java:118)
>                                                                                                  at com.google.polo.ssl.SslUtil.generateX509V3Certificate(SslUtil.java:165)
>                                                                                                  at com.example.google.tv.anymotelibrary.connection.KeyStoreManager.generateAppCertificate(KeyStoreManager.java:154)

I have absolutely no idea where the BouncyCastleProvider comes from and how I can adjust my code to fix this exception.

Again, I'm not even sure if I'm not wasting my time with this a bit older code from the Google TV days to get the functionality I need between the phone and TV app.

Help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

BouncyCastleProvider is for secure connections. It may not be included by default in Android. You may be able to find it through a jar or gradle link.

You may also want to visit this answer, [Is there a smaller version of the BouncyCastleProvider on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798737/is-there-a-smaller-version-of-the-bouncycastleprovider-on-android?rq=1), which uses a similar library compatible with Android.

Comment: The .jar file for the BouncyCastleProvider is in my lib directory. I also tried it with a smaller version (As suggested in your link). Sadly, still the same problem.